# CSS Multiple grouped elements with margins

Tags: html, css, margin

Take this HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="block">Hello</div>
    <div class="block">Hello</div>
    <div class="block">Hello</div>
    <div class="block">Hello</div>
</div>
```

With the companion CSS:

```
div.block
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1px;
    background: red;
}
```

The result of this is four blocks, which have between them **2 pixels** of space (1px from the right margin of the left block and 1px from the left margin of the right block).

Is there a way that I can achieve a similar effect to border-collapse? ie. I want there to be only one pixel of margin between adjacent blocks.

This is a basic example of often more complex situations that I run into, and I don't want to get around it by by anything similar to only setting `margin-left` to 1 pixel etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways to this

One of them is

```
div.block
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 1px 1px 1px 0;
    background: red;
}
div.block:last-child {
    margin: 1px 0 1px 0;
}
```

Another is

```
div.block+div.block { margin-left: 1px; }
```

You can check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/cV6jU/) of both way [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/cV6jU/)

Comment: I like the latter option, is this heavily supported?

Comment: It is supported IE8+, buggy in safari, opera 9.5+, chrome 2.0+, see http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/adjacentsiblingselector

Comment: @MartyWallace, no they are not widely supported although most of the modern browsers now does. If compatibility is necessary for old browsers, you can take help of a javascript.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the CSS selector [`:first-child` and `:last-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html) to alter the first and last `<div>`?

```
div.block
{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 2px 1px 2px 0;
    background: red;
}
div.block:first-child {
    margin-left: 2px;
}
div.block:last-child {
    margin-right: 2px;
}
```

Comment: These selectors aren't supported well enough.

Comment: Support documented here: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-lastchild (no support in IE till 9, ff 3.0+, safari 3.1+, opera 9.5+, chrome 2.0+

Answer (score 0):

If you can alter the markup itself, then I guess we can have a cross browser compatible solution:

```
<div class="block"> <div class="block_2"></div> </div>
```

and then apply the css like:

```
div.block{float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
div.block_2{width:99px; height:100px; background-color:red}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign a class for last block called 'last'.
The set margin-right of every block to 1px. 
Set margin-right of block that has last class to 0.
.block.last { margin-right: 0px; }

Pseudo selectors like forst-child and last-child are not well supported so I think this is the best option you have.